# Kafka Consumer optimization and should I use Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a Kafka consumer to consume encrypted data(~1MB) stream and decrypt them before adding them to the S3 bucket. It takes ~20mins to process 1000 records, and if I remove the encryption logic and run the same, it takes less than 3mins to process 1000records.

The following are the configs I am currently using.

```
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1000000
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 655360
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

The topic has 10partitions. I consumed with multiple consumers(1-10) by assigning them to the same consumer group. But no matter how many consumers I use, it consumed the same amount of data in the given time.

How do I make consumers faster? And can Apache Spark help in this?

Comment: Server fault site would be more appropriate for your question. SO is for programming questions

Comment: Spark won't consume any faster than a plain, distributed consumer application with the same consumer properties. The Kafka APIs are the same and Spark adds more overhead, so if anything, it'd be slower